# EA cannot find the path specified when generating XML

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a model (and EA 12.1) which I have inherited from a predecessor.  We use it to generate XML schemas.  But when I try to right-click the << XSDschema  MyModel>> and select Code Engineering...>Generate XSD Schema... it does some processing, and then fails to save the output with the error "The system cannot find the path specified".

Investigation has revealed that if you create the folders C:\Program files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\XSDs, XML and XSL the output files are written there. Not ideal in an environment where you don't have access to change/create these folders.

My question is (as I am fairly new to EA) why is it using that folder, and how can I get it to use another? Is it the installation or the model that is specifying this?

I note that the shortcut that launches EA has the Sparx Systems\EA folder as its initial directory, but trying to change that stopped EA starting up when I tried.

Monathan

Answer (score 2):

EA is trying to generate to that folder because you (or your predecessor) told it to, it is not a default setting or anything.

For each «XSDschema» package you can set the file location. If you open the properties of that package you'll see this:

[image]

In the dialog for generating the XSD you can change it as well:

[image]

Comment: Geert, Thank you for your prompt answer.  I checked the properties screen and it contains F:\my documents\MyModel\MyModel.xsd (F: being my home directory share), but am still getting the error!

There must be something else at work here ...

Comment: I don't have that folder in program files and I've never seen a reference to that specific folder. I think you should look into model/local settings.

Comment: A little more information.  If I change F: to \\adserver\dfs\homedirs\myusername\ documents\MyModel\XSDs\MyModel.xsd it doesn't give the error for the file.